# Package fontenc creates error after upgrading system

Tags: font-encodings, debian

I recently upgraded my debian installation (testing branch), and now my documents won't properly compile using fontenc. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\begin{document}

blablabla

\end{document}
```

Compiling the file using Kile then gives me the error that PDFLatex finished with exit code 1, and:

> /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty:115:Undefined control sequence \xdef\@fontenc@load@list

Removing the \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} removes this error, but i get a warning that OT1 encoding shouldn't be used with french.

What I tried so far, based on some frantic googling:

- `apt reinstall texlive` and `apt install texlive-full`
- `fmtutil-sys --all`

Comment: Don't panic. this means the format you are using has been not regenerated. You probably have a local format that shadows the one created with fmtutil-sys. Check with `kpsewhich --all -engine=pdftex pdflatex.fmt` which formats you have.

Comment: Running the command gave me 2 results:

user@debian:~$ kpsewhich --all -engine=pdftex pdflatex.fmt
/home/user/.texlive2019/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt
/var/lib/texmf/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt

I just renamed the first one pdflatex.old, and now everything is working fine, so problem solved. Thank you !

Comment: At best remove all fmt file from `/home/user/.texlive2019/texmf-var/web2c`